# Can become Probability mass function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image: my question]

There are my question and my answer

By definition, when

- $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ which is element of real number
- Range =$\{x:f(x)>0\}$ is finite or countable
- sum of $f(a) =1$  $a$ is elements of range

Then $f$ defined in $\mathbb R$  is called probability mass function.

By strict definition, should PMF  be defined on $\mathbb R$? Can I define $f(x)$ on $\mathbb N$?
If it can, I don't have to redefine $f(x)$ to $\mathbb R$

I want to strict answer by definition.
In my book there is no saying about PMF defined on $\mathbb N$   but  just defined on $\mathbb R$ and in some $x$, define $f=0$
it is strange to defined on $\mathbb R$ always...
In doing it,  is there reason?

Comment: probability mass function usually refers to a density function of discrete random variable (takes only countable many values), so yes, your function works just fine on $\mathbb N^{>0}$

Comment: Thanks. So when i define f on N, f can be probability mass function itself? And i dont have to make f to be defined on R by redefining ..?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your last comment

> So when I define $f$ on $\mathbb N$, $f$ can be probability mass function itself? And I dont have to make $f$ to be defined on $\mathbb R$ by redefining

that's right. You define your probability mass function $f$ on the positive natural numbers. Of course you could extend the support of the function $f$ to $\mathbb R^{+}$, but as you've already realized, this would not lead to a density at all.

Since it indeed holds, that

There is nothing weird going on here, just remember, that your cumulative distribution function looks somehow like
$$
F(x):=\mathbf P(X\leq x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\mathbf P(X=i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}f_x(i)
$$ 
so there is no positive probability that your random variable ever takes values outside your discrete set.

Since it indeed holds via a telescoping sum, that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbf P(X=i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_x(i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac1{i(i+1)}=1
$$
you're done with proving the property of a mass function since it also holds that $f_x\geq0$.

Comment: "positive natural numbers" :)

Comment: @K.Hoffmann yeah...well, some people define $\mathbb N:=\mathbb{Z}^{+}\cup \{0\}$ which often results in some irritation when speaking with guys who don't :)